# How do I use a dynamic JS library (wavesurfer.js) in a functional React component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, wavesurfer.js

I have the following functional React component that is using wavesurfer.js

```js
import * as React from "react"
import * as WaveSurfer from 'wavesurfer.js'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faPlayCircle, faPauseCircle } from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons'
import { IconDefinition } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'

interface WaveformPlayerProps {
  audioUrl: string
}

const WaveformPlayer = (props: WaveformPlayerProps) => {
  const [playing, setPlaying] = React.useState(false)
  const [audioContext, setAudioContext] = React.useState(new AudioContext())
  const [waveform, setWaveform] = React.useState(null)

  const waveformRef = React.useRef();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (waveformRef.current) {
      const wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
        audioContext: audioContext,
        container: waveformRef.current
      });

      wavesurfer.on('finish', togglePlayPause)
      wavesurfer.load(props.audioUrl)
      setWaveform(wavesurfer)
    }
  }, [])

  function togglePlayPause(): void {
    if (audioContext.state == "suspended") {
      audioContext.resume()
    }

    waveform.playPause()
    setPlaying(!playing)
  }

  function stateButtonIcon(): IconDefinition {
    if (playing) {
      return faPauseCircle
    } else {
      return faPlayCircle
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button id="waveformAudioControl" className="button is-large" onClick={togglePlayPause}>
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={stateButtonIcon()} />
      </button>

      <div ref={waveformRef}>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default WaveformPlayer
```

I think the only way I can access a WaveSurfer object outside of `useEffect` is by using `useState` however this doesn’t feel right to me as the WaveSurfer component shouldn’t completely re-render if some state changes in the component (e.g. user presses play/pause button). This leads me to think that my approach is not correct?

Edit: forgot to mention that `waveform.playPause()` fails because it is null when the play button is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { Fragment, useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import WaveSurfer from 'wavesurfer.js'
import audioFile from './../assets/sample-wave-file-5MB.wav'

const WaveSurferStatelessForm = () => {
  let [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false)
  let [waveSurfer, setWaveSurfer] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    setWaveSurfer(WaveSurfer.create({
      container: '#waveform'
    }))
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    if(waveSurfer) {
      waveSurfer.load(audioFile)
    }
  }, [waveSurfer])

  const togglePlayPause = () => {
    waveSurfer.playPause()
    setIsPlaying(!isPlaying)
  }

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div id="waveform" ></div>
      <button onClick={() => togglePlayPause()}>{isPlaying ? '||' : '+'}</button>
    </Fragment>
  )
}

export default WaveSurferStatelessForm
```

Your `waveform.playPause()` fails after clicking the play button because you are updating state, `playing`, which will cause your component to re-render. Since your useEffect runs only on the first render, once the state changes your waveform will be set to null and useEffect will not re-instantiate it when the component re-renders. To solve this you need to either set the waveform to state, so it is always instantiated, or add the `playing` variable inside the `[]` so useEffect will re-instantiate the waveform each time the component re-renders. My solution above uses the former with a detailed explanation below.

Set the waveSurfer object after the first render, this way the `<div id="waveform" ></div>` will be mounted to the DOM before you create the waveSurfer object.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setWaveSurfer(WaveSurfer.create({
      container: '#waveform'
    }))
  }, [])
```

Now that the waveSurfer object is set, we need to load the audio. This `useEffect` will run twice, but only load the audio once the waveSurfer object has been set, which will be the last time this `useEffect` is called. Prior to this, the waveSurfer object is null.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if(waveSurfer) {
      waveSurfer.load(audioFile)
    }
  }, [waveSurfer])
```

As a note, `useEffect` will always run after the first render, then on any state change passed to the `[]`. If there are no `[]` it will run after every render. So you don't need to check if the div exists `if (waveformRef.current)` it will always exist because `useEffect` is executing after the first render. In a statefull or `class` component this is similar to `componentDidMount`

Answer (score 0):

The best I could come up with is declaring `const waveform = React.useRef<WaveSurfer | null>(null)` and using `waveform.current` in the rest of the file.